# Can't add a network printer - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

I have an HP 2600n installed on a SBS2003 server. This printer works fine when I print from the server itself and also from my Windows 7 computer #1. From my Windows 7 #2, it doesn't work. I get the error message that I need to install the driver.

The error message is in french but here it the translation.

> No drivers has been found
>
> Windows is unable to find a driver for HP Color Laserjet 2600n on the network. To find a driver manually, click ok. If not, click on cancel and contact your sys adm.

I reinstalled from scratch the printer, deleted the driver... Still no luck

Any takers?

Comment: Are all computers running 64-bit or 32-bit or mixed? I've seen many printer issues with 64bit Win7 trying to pull from 32bit servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the one Windows 7 machine is 32-bit, and the other (with the driver problem) is 64-bit.

I'm also assuming that you're connecting to this printer via a share from the SBS server.

So if my guess and assumption is correct, you'll need to get the 64-bit driver into the SBS server so that it can send it to the Win7 64-bit system when it tries to connect to that printer share.

The first trick to this is that both the 32 and 64-bit drivers need to be the same name, or they won't both associate to the printer.

Go get the newest driver(s) for that 2600n printer from HP: [32-bit here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=446154&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=446153&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4062), [64-bit here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=446154&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=446153&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4063)

Replace the existing 32-bit driver (at the server) with the one you just downloaded.

Then install the 64-bit driver you also just downloaded -- The trick here is that if SBS2003 is 32-bit, you can't load a 64-bit driver directly, you have to do it from the 64-bit client:

> 1. On the x64 machine, from Start > Run, type \\servername, where
>      servername = the name of the x86 print
>      server.
> 2. In the list of shares, open the Printers folder.
> 3. Right-click in the Printers folder [window you just opened] and select
>      Server Properties.
> 4. Go to the Drivers tab [select the x64 driver] and add a new x64 driver.

The above steps were obtained from [here](http://blog.blueivy.co.uk/2008/04/25/installing-a-64-bit-printer-driver-in-small-business-server-2003-or-any-32-bit-server-os/), which explains it pretty well.

If my assumptions and guesses are wrong, you'll need to provide more applicable information before we can help you. :)

Comment: Should I need the SBS2003 x64 driver? If so, there is no x64 based driver for this printer.

Comment: Nope, you want the driver that the 64-bit client will use since they're the ones who will be using it (the server will simply be handing it out). :)

Comment: Ok, I confirm! My issue is now fixed.

Comment: Nice... It sucked the first time I ran into that too.